# Are dots allowed in keys in ngx-translate

Tags: ngx-translate

I have a problem in the codebase that I'm working on right now related to **keys with dots**.

Basically, the **i18n** **JSON** contains something like:

```
{
  a: {
    title: 'Title for a'
  },
  b: {
    title: 'Title for b'
  },
  'a.b': {
    title: 'Title for a.b'
  }
}
```

In the html we are accessing it

```
{{ 'a.title' | translate }}
```

In short, these are the results for the existing keys

| key | Result | Works |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a` | `{title: 'Title for a'}` | ✅ |
| `a.title` | Title for a | ✅ |
| `b` | `{title: 'Title for b'}` | ✅ |
| `b.title` | Title for b | ✅ |
| `a.b` | **undefined** | ❌ |
| `a.b.title` | **undefined** | ❌ |

Tried to search in the documentation and the Github issues but there's nothing that points that this is allowed/disallowed.

---

Furthermore, I debugged the code and saw that the method responsible to get the value for a given key is **getValue**  in [translate.parser.ts](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/3a4c7ee9e56a86f72a42dd3590122b0db7667779/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.parser.ts#L41).

This specific method isn't able to deal with cases where there's a key with dots for which there's another key with the initial part of said key.
For example, if we have two keys 'a' and 'a.b' but 'a' is a **string** then the method works. If in this example 'a' was an object then it doesn't work.

I also reckon that it's hard to implement since we can have a case like this:

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
       title: 'Title for a'
    }
  },
  'a.b': {
    title: 'a.b title'
  }
}
```

If you pass the following {{ 'a.b.title' | translate }} which one would be translated?

---

My possibilities are:

1. Replace all keys with dots by underscores or something else
2. Create **parser** that extends the  **TranslateDefaultParser** and re-implements the **getValue** method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own post, YES dots are allowed in keys BUT it can cause you trouble easily if you have composite keys.

My solution was to flatten all translations which makes the underlying code O(1) to get each key and allows us to use dots even in composite keys.

Flattening all translations means that the following:

```
{
    a: {
       b: {
          title: 'Title for b',
          label: 'Label for b'
       }
   }
}
```

Becomes:

```
'a.b.title': 'Title for b'
'a.b.label': 'Label for b'
```

Answer (score 1):

by default while using `{{ 'a.b.title' | translate }}` ngx-translate search this

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
       title: 'Title for a'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the code that's exactly it.